# How many cells are there in C. elegans in each hour of its life?

Tags: cell-biology, homework, biostatistics

I'm a high school student planning to write a math essay to model changes in the number of cells in a living organism over time. *C. elegans* is the only organism that I know with a known number and lineage of cells. I found the full lineage of cells in *C. elegans* [here](https://www.wormatlas.org/celllineages.html), which is plotted in respect of time. However, counting the number of cells in those diagrams is impractical. So, is there a summarized database for the number of cells in each hour in the life of *C. elegans*?

Comment: Could you clarify " write a math essay to model changes in the number of cells in a living organism over time" -- what kind of essay or model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lineages provided at [WormAtlas](https://web.archive.org/web/20210812061823/https://www.wormatlas.org/celllineages.html) include references to the original publications. Concerning the embryonic lineage at the top of the page, the corresponding paper was published in 1983.<sup>**1**</sup> Looking at that publication, we see that the authors provide a summary figure depicting nuclei counts over the course of 800 minutes, from the first embryonic cleavage until hatching:

> [image: Figure 4 from Sulston et al 1983, showing a line graph depicting counts of live nuclei in C. elegans over 800 minutes]
>
> FIG. 4. Marker events and count of living nuclei during embryogenesis. Fertilisation is normally at -50 min. Note that the comma stage is defined in a precise way, as the moment at which the ventral surface of the tail lies perpendicular to the long axis of the egg.

Post-embryonic nuclei counts for young worms and adults are given in Tables 2 and 3 of a 1977 publication by the same first author.<sup>**2**</sup> I can find no data on hour-by-hour cell counts over the interval of an adult worm's lifetime, though such a dataset might be out there.

---

**References**

1. Sulston JE, Schierenberg E, White JG, Thomson JN. The embryonic cell lineage of the nematode *Caenorhabditis elegans*. *Dev Biol*. 1983 Nov;100(1):64-119.
2. Sulston JE, Horvitz HR. Post-embryonic cell lineages of the nematode, *Caenorhabditis elegans*. *Dev Biol*. 1977 Mar;56(1):110-56.